# EF Core 2.1 adding unwanted column to schema because of owned entity

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I have an owned entity `Price` which is used by two other entities.  When I run the schema generation script, EF is adding an additional column to one of the other parent entities.  How can I get this column removed?  In the table `SaleCommissions`, the column `Price_SaleCommissionId` is added as a Not Null int and doesn't have any form of keys.

```
[Owned]
class Price {
  public decimal Amount {get;set;}
  public string Code {get;set;
}
```

```
class Order {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public Price Price {get;set;}
}
```

```
class SaleCommission {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public Price Price {get;set;}
}
```

```
-- Generated schema
Table: Orders
Columns:
  Id
  Price_Amount
  Price_Code

Table: SaleCommissions
Columns:
  Id
  Price_Amount
  Price_Code
  Price_SaleCommissionId <-- Why is this column added, and how can I have it removed?
```

Comment: Do you use a modelbuilder configuration?

Comment: @Stefan, for other tables, yes, so far nothing for these tables.

Comment: Did you specified `[Key]` with one of the properties? Is this your actual code or is it tailor made for this question?

Comment: First of all you definitely need primary key column defined for each table, I think.

Comment: I don't have `[Key]` specified because EF automatically uses `Id` as a primary key column.  Turns out I needed to use the `OwnsOne` method in the modelBuilder.

Comment: According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/april/data-points-ef-core-2-owned-entities-and-temporary-work-arounds#mapping-a-value-object-as-an-ef-core-owned-entity) : "EF Core, however, can’t automatically infer owned entities. You must specify this in the DbContext Fluent API mappings in the OnModelCreating method using the new OwnsOne method to specify which property of that entity is the owned entity." Auto mapping owned types seems ef core 2.2 feature.

Comment: Can't repro this using EF core 2.1.14 on Sql Server.